# Laravel 5 installer only creates empty folder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am following the [Laracasts: Build your first app in laravel - episode 2](https://laracasts.com/series/build-your-first-app-in-laravel/episodes/2). I have also went through the [Laravel 5 Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0). After installing the laravel installer I run 'laravel new blog' but all it does is create an empty folder. Why is that?

My bash_profile file reads

export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/bin:$PATH 
export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH 
export PATH=$PATH:~/.composer/vendor/bin/
export PATH=$PATH:~/.composer/vendor/bin
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"

Comment: Some step by step guide here http://laravel.com/docs/5.0

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention I followed that too.

Comment: Do you get? 'Crafting application...
Application ready! Build something amazing.' When you run the command in terminal? An alternative could be to install it via Composer.

Comment: Nope, no error. It just creates a new empty folder with the name. I am assuming that can be run from my local machine rather than in the homestead.
If I try composer installer on my machine I get the error that I need mcrypt. It works ok on homestead. If I installed mcrypt would it work with laravel installer then?

Comment: PHP >= 5.4, Mcrypt PHP Extension, OpenSSL PHP Extension, Mbstring PHP Extension, Tokenizer PHP Extension. Its all in docs...

Answer (score 4):

It happens because it is trying to use the old laravel installer installed on /usr/local/bin.

You just have to delete that with:

sudo rm /usr/local/bin/laravel

And that's all, this worked for me!

Comment: Exactly what was needed; I should have realized.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case (Debian 7.8)

First try to call the installer by its full path:

```
/home/_your_username_/.composer/vendor/bin/laravel new _your_projectname_
```

If it works like that then I guess you have your $PATH setup in the wrong order.
I first had installed laravel 4 installer in `/usr/local/bin/laravel` following this instructions http://laravel.com/docs/4.1

Then I installed the new laravel 5 installer following this instructions:
http://laravel.com/docs/5.0

So the problem was, because I used

```
export PATH="$PATH:~/.composer/vendor/bin"
```

to add the binary to my `$PATH` it was placed at the end of the list and the old installer was found first. Use

```
export PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

instead, so it gets added in front of `/usr/local/bin/`
Then it should work.